# multiple chain reuse in catalyst

Tags: perl, chaining, catalyst

I am a perl & catalyst newbie and I have been playing around with [Catalyst::DispatchType::Chained](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::DispatchType::Chained)
and I am wondering if it is possible to allow for chained paths to be rewired in different patterns :

```
/hello/*/world/*
/world/*/hello/*
/hello/*
/world/*
```

or do you have to have a uniquely defined endpoint for each path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be two chains with two endpoints:

```
sub hello : PathPart("hello") : CaptureArgs(1) {# /hello/*/...} 
#-> 
sub world : chained "/hello" : PathPart("world") : Args(1) {# /hello/*/world/*}

sub world_base : PathPart("/world") : CaptureArgs(1) {# world/*/...}
#->
sub hello_world chained "world_base" PathPart("hello") Args(1) {# /world/*/hello/*}
```

However, if they both do the same thing, just forward to a method that does what you want in both methods, I would suggest.

Forwarding can be weird across controllers, I usually have a method for that in my Main.pm. If you need further help with that, feel free to ask.

Be a bit careful about "chains" and "paths": A chain always needs an endpoint, that is, a `sub Chained` with only Args( ) at the end, as above.

Paths are matched via PathPart.

for example

```
sub base Pathpart( "" ) : CaptureArgs(1) {}

sub hello Chained("base"): PathPart("hello") : Args(0){ 
# this is an endpoint
# path is /*/hello

sub hello_world : Chained("base") : PathPart("hello") : Args(1){
# another end to the chain started at base
# path is /*/hello/*

sub again : Chained("hello") : PathPart("") :CaptureArgs(1) {
# path is /*/hello/*/ ...
sub hello_universe : Chained("hello") : Pathpart("universe") : Args(1){
# another endpoint to another chain
# path is /*/hello/*/universe/*
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for accepting! You could have waited for Christmas, but I do not celebrate, dunno how you guessed ;)